# Как настроить DNS для Ansible на Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, ansible

Есть такая замечательная статья на RedHat https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/dns-configuration-ansible
как мне модифицировать роль для Ubuntu 20.04?
Там просто netplan вместо /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

Comment: Ну `netplan` хранит конфиг в yaml. Ansible оперирует json/yaml. Ты пишешь `vars: my_netplan_conf: <тут прям сырой ямл для нетплан>`, а потом модуль `copy` с `content`. Или ты прям про конкретные настройки для нетплана? Ну это надо уже читать доки по нему и гуглить конкретные примеры настроек.